# Sending Direct Mail in iPhone via SKPSMTPMessage

Tags: iphone, smtp

I am trying to send direct mail.As far I know, for direct mail i.e no other controller should appear,The mail should be sent on a button click from myController,so, we can’t use `MFMailComposeViewController`.So, I am using SKPSMTPMessage. For SKPSMTPMessage, I have done primary settings and with temp data I can send mail.Few things I didn’t get: like..

```
testMsg.fromEmail = @“from@gmail.com”;

testMsg.toEmail = @“to@gmail.com”;

testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";

testMsg.requiresAuth = YES;

testMsg.login = @“from@gmail.com";

testMsg.pass = @"mypassword”;
```

Here, we have to pass testMsg.login/testMsg.pass. Right now m using some temporary userID and respective password.But in my application nowhere I asking /getting any details of his password, only i’m getting his Email ID. So, my question is...Is it possible to send mail even if m not taking user's password. If not, what is the most appropriate way to send mail using SKPSMTPMessage

Answer (score 0):

Following code for just applying the settings over following code.

```
 + (void)initialize {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableDictionary *defaultsDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"me@example.com", @"fromEmail",
                                               @"you@example.com", @"toEmail",
                                               @"smtp.example.com", @"relayHost",
                                               @"me@example.com", @"login",
                                               @"SekritSquirrel", @"pass",
                                               [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"requiresAuth",
                                               [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], @"wantsSecure", nil];

    [userDefaults registerDefaults:defaultsDictionary];
}
```

Comment: Thanx anyway, but u didn’t read my question carefully. I don’t want to use `MFMailComposeViewController`.

Comment: But in this scenario from where I will get user’s Email password? I think without user’s password this will not work.